# Display custom payment field in Woocommerce Admin, Orders and emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I need to display my custom checkout fields in admin orders page, thank_you and email notifications.

I am using [Validate and save additional checkout field for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865862/validate-and-save-additional-checkout-field-for-specific-payment-gateway-in-wooc/53868329#53868329) answer code to show, validate and save my custom field.

From [Woocommerce display custom field data on admin order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833449/woocommerce-display-custom-field-data-on-admin-order-details/46835302#46835302) I am trying to display my custom field saved inputted value.

This is the code I have so far:

```
// Display field value on the order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 
    'show_Ean_nummer_in_admin', 10, 1 );
    function show_Ean_nummer_in_admin ( $order ){
    // Get "ean" custom field value
    $udfyld_ean = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_udfyld_ean', true );

    // Display "ean" custom field value
    echo '<p>'.__('EAN', 'woocommerce') . $udfyld_ean . '</p>';
} 

// Display field value on the order emails  
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'ean_in_emails' 50, 1 );
function ean_in_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
      // Get "ean" custom field value
    $udfyld_ean = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_udfyld_ean', true );

    // Display "ean" custom field value
    echo '<p>'.__('EAN', 'woocommerce') . $udfyld_ean . '</p>';
}

// Display field value in thank you
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'ean_in_thankyou' );
function ean_in_thankyou() {
    // Get "ean" custom field value
    $udfyld_ean = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_udfyld_ean', true );
    // Display "ean" custom field value
    echo '<p>'.__('EAN', 'woocommerce') . $udfyld_ean . '</p>';
}
```

But It's not working. The field does get appended to the database, but does not display anywhere:

[image: metakey in database]

How can I display the field properly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should explain what do you mean by _its not working_. Is it giving any error or showing blank value for `_udfyld_ean`?

Comment: thanks. It's not showing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will display your "Udfyld EAN" custom field value in orders and email notifications:

1) To display that in Woocommerce order admin single pages:

```
// Display field value on the admin order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'custom_field_admin_display_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_field_admin_display_order_meta( $order ){
    $business_address = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'Business Address?', true );
    if( $udfyld_ean = $order->get_meta('_udfyld_ean') )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Udfyld EAN', 'woocommerce').': </strong> ' . $udfyld_ean . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.*

[image]

2) To display that on Order received, Order view and email notifications you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_udfyld_ean_row_to_order_totals', 10, 3 );
function add_udfyld_ean_row_to_order_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {;

    $new_total_rows = [];

    foreach($total_rows as $key => $total ){
        $new_total_rows[$key] = $total;

        if( $order->get_meta('_udfyld_ean') && 'payment_method' === $key ){
            $new_total_rows['udfyld_ean'] = array(
                'label' => __('Udfyld EAN', 'woocommerce'),
                'value' => esc_html( $order->get_meta('_udfyld_ean') ),
            );
        }
    }

    return $new_total_rows;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: neither 1 or 2 output any new content in my admin/thank_you, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are using following code to fetch the value of `_udfyld_ean` :

```
get_post_meta( $order_id, '_udfyld_ean', true );
```

But the problem is, you have not defined `$order_id` anywhere. You will need to pass valid value of order ID to get the expected output.